# Scaling the height of all elements in a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem adjusting the height of the elements in a row.The problem is that I can't adjust the size of the image to the panel on the right.Or panel to image. I tried to use height and width style image. but i don't know how to adjust the second column :(

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-2">
          <img src="img.png" alt="image">
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-5">
          <div class="panel panel-info tile panelClose panelRefresh">
             <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"></h4>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body pt0">
                <div class="progressbar-stats-1">
                   <div class="stats">
                      <i class="l-basic-chronometer"></i>
                      <div id="visitor_number" class="stats-number" data-from="0" data-o="0">0</div>
                   </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: create a working environment dear so we can help you better. on other hand img-responsive will resize your image to max-width:100% by default. try removing it meanwhile

Comment: After removing img-responsive image goes out of div :(

Comment: yes, but you can give it width and height they way you want, isn't this what you requested?